# Check if a list is sorted case insensitive

Tags: java, list, recursion

For my intro to Java class I created a method that takes this list and outputs a new sorted list. Now I am trying to create a method that checks if this list is sorted or not (both are case insensitive). I tried to go the easy way and use this.equals(this.sorted()) but it's not working since when I am comparing a already sorted list is outputting false instead of true. I need some guidance. I can't use arrays or loops just recursion.

```
    import tester.Tester;


   // to represent a list of Strings
    interface ILoString {
        //prodces a new list, sorted in alphabetical order case insensitive
        ILoString sort();
        //helps sort() sort a list
        ILoString sortHelp(String acc);
        //determines whether this list is sorted in alphabetical order,
        //in a case-insensitive way.
        boolean isSorted();
    }
    // to represent an empty list of Strings
    class MtLoString implements ILoString {
        MtLoString(){}

       //prodces a new list, sorted in alphabetical order case insensitive
        public ILoString sort() {
          return this;
    }
        //helps sort() sort a list
        public ILoString sortHelp(String acc) {
          return new ConsLoString(acc, this);
        }

        //determines whether this list is sorted in alphabetical order,
        //in a case-insensitive way.
        public boolean isSorted() {
          return true;
        }
    }

    // to represent a nonempty list of Strings
    class ConsLoString implements ILoString {
        String first;
        ILoString rest;

        ConsLoString(String first, ILoString rest){
            this.first = first;
            this.rest = rest;  
        }



        //determines whether this list is sorted in alphabetical order,
        //in a case-insensitive way.
        public boolean isSorted() {
          return this.equals(this.sort());
        }


        //prodces a new list, sorted in alphabetical order case insensitive
        public ILoString sort() {
          return this.rest.sort().sortHelp(this.first);
        }

        //helps to sort the names in this ConsLoString
        public ILoString sortHelp(String acc) {
            if ( acc.compareToIgnoreCase(this.first) < 0) {
              return new ConsLoString(acc, this);
            }
              else {
                return new ConsLoString(this.first, this.rest.sortHelp(acc));
              }

            }


    }

    // to represent examples for lists of strings
    class ExamplesStrings{

        ILoString mary = new ConsLoString("Mary ",
                        new ConsLoString("had ",
                            new ConsLoString("a ",
                                new ConsLoString("little ",
                                    new ConsLoString("lamb.", new MtLoString())))));
        ILoString marySorted = new ConsLoString("a ",
            new ConsLoString("had ",
                new ConsLoString("lamb.",
                    new ConsLoString("little ",
                        new ConsLoString("Mary ", new MtLoString())))));

     // test the method sort for the lists of Strings
        boolean testSort(Tester t){
            return 
                t.checkExpect(this.mary.sort(),this.marySorted)&&
                t.checkExpect(this.marySorted.sort(),this.marySorted);
        }

        //test the method isSorted
        boolean testisSorted(Tester t){
          return 
              t.checkExpect(this.mary.isSorted(),false)&&
              t.checkExpect(this.marySorted.isSorted(),true);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think your question is much too vague to get any answers. I think there are many single problems in your code that can´t be addressed too easily.

Comment: So, the question you have is how to implement `isSorted` using recursion instead of an iterative approach?

Comment: @Lothar yes basically

Comment: Without a method `getFirst` in `ILoString` I find it hard to get to a solution. Is the interface you've provided complete? On second thought it's essentially the implementation of `sortHelp` with `boolean` as return type and corresponding returned values for the two conditions in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try just creating a new list, which is a sorted version of the list your checking. Then you check that sorted list against your original list. If they are equal, then your original list was sorted.

```
List<String> myStings = new ArrayList<>();
  myStings.add("Mary");
  myStings.add("had");
  myStings.add("a");
  myStings.add("little");
  myStings.add("lamb");

myStings = myStings.stream().map(x -> x.toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> sortedList = myStings.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("Unsorted list: " + myStings);
System.out.println("Sorted list: " + sortedList);
System.out.println("Was it a sorted list: " + myStings.equals(sortedList));
```

The list `equals()` method checks that both lists are of the same size and that all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal.

Oh, I've just added a step above to convert all the elements in your list to lowercase. Only difference it'll make in the example above is where the word "Mary" sits in your sorted list, but overall shouldn't make a difference to what you are trying to achieve.

UPDATE:

So the reason this method does not work specifically for your implementation is because you are not actually using Lists (or anything from `java.util.Collections` for that matter). You've created your own implementation of a linked list. Hence when you use the `.equals()` method your actually using the default implementation of this method found in `java.lang.Object`. The default implementation does not check what's in the Object, but rather it checks if the the Objects share the same **memory address**. Where your`sort()` method is returning a *sorted* list, it's a different object sitting in a different address in memory, hence `.equals()` will report it as `false`;

What you need to do is actually check the variables in your object (not the memory address). In order to do so you will need to `Override` the default implementation of `.equals()` in your `ConsLoString` class, because you actually want to do comparisons on the variable `first`

So it'll look something like this...

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  ConsLoString toCompare = (ConsLoString) o;
  if(this.first == toCompare.first) {
    if (this.rest != null && toCompare.rest != null) {
      return this.rest.equals(toCompare.rest);
    } else {
      return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
  } else {
    return Boolean.FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am a bit confused I thought thats what I was doing when returning  this.equals(this.sorted());  I thought I was comparing this list with the sorted version of this list.

Comment: Check the update I made above. You actually not using the Java implementation of List, as found in `java.util.Collections`. Instead you've just created a List using Objects and the default implementation of `.equals()` on Objects checks **memory allocation**.

Comment: Did this resolve your issue? Please check the box on the left to mark as resolved. Thanks.